Meaning of the radical symbol in the field of complex numbers
If I have $y=\sqrt x$, where $y$ and $x$ belong to the field of complex numbers. Is it necessary to specify if the symbol "$\surd$" refers to the principal root? Is there a convention?
For example: $y=\sqrt 4$. If "$\surd$" is the principal square root, then $y$ takes a single value. But if "$\surd$" refers to finding all the roots, then $y$ takes two values. I give this example, because if I am working in the field of real numbers, $y$ only takes one value which is $2$.

As a rule, I don't like using  $\sqrt $ in complex numbers, because of the ambiguity. $x^{1/2}$ might be clearer, but yes, you should always specify a branch

@ThomasAndrews That is why it is preferred to define the imaginary unit as $\mathrm{i}^2=-1$ instead of $\mathrm{i}=\sqrt{-1}$?

No, it's because the notation $\sqrt{-1}$ has no meaning, even in principle, if you don't already have available some object $x$ for which $x^2=-1$.

Sometimes preferred, although students are usually taught $\sqt{-1},$ and I wouldn't use $(-1)^{1/2}$ with a beginner. I sometimes suggest thinking of, the complex numbers as adding two square root s of $-1,$ $i$ and $j,$ with $i+j=0.$ Neither is the primary square roots of $-1,$ and it explains why conjugation is an automorphism - it just amounts to switching $i$ and $j.$

Conventions are not universal.  Some people use $\sqrt{z}$ for the principal branch of the square root and $z^{1/2}$ for the multivalued version, but others do not.  When writing, it is  a good idea to tell the reader what convention you are using.
